# Progress indicator for boost serialization

Tags: progress, boost-serialization

I have a document structure implemented with boost serialization, however when I save/load a document it can take a long time. I would need to have a progress indication of how far the save/load has gotten.

Is there a way to use boost iostreams source for this ? That way I would be able to implement a source taking the data from my input stream.

More ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try creating a window that just states

**"Saving to file..."** / **"Loading from file..."**

that gets destroyed once the saving/loading operation ends.

You can also have it update the **"Save to file"** message to **"File saved"** once the save operation completes.

It's not an ideal solution but at least your users won't be scratching their heads wondering what the save/load operation is doing.  I've looked for a similar solution myself but found none.  Let me know if you find something.

Comment: Actually, I did find one. I implemented a input buffer based on basic_streambuf, which keeps track of the number of characters read from the input stream, and calls a callback with a percentage of how much the input stream has been consumed. With saving there is really no way to know how much that is left of the operation, as you don't know from the start how many characters the operation will end up with... I'll post my solution here after it has been cleaned up :)

Comment: Great! I would love to see it!

Comment: @Robert do you read gcount() on the buffer repeatedly? Does that work?